# Need to run celery worker during Django unittest

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am working on Django based web app. During unittest, I need to write a test which needs "Celery worker" running in the background.

I have already used:

```
CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS=True
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True
BROKER_BACKEND='memory
```

In over_ride settings, but these are not running celery worker for me in background when needed.

Any help would much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Celery won't get run by Django automatically. 
You can start a worker process by running from your project root:

```
$ celery -A my_proj worker
```

`my_proj` should be the application name you configured with `app = Celery('my_proj')`